# Correct way to add location header to responses in NancyFx

Tags: c#, rest, nancy

I'm using Nancy as a rest back-end for my application.
Currently I've managed to add location header to my responses with this hack :

```
var headerUri = Request.Url.SiteBase + Request.Path + "/" + processedModel.Id.ToString();

Response response = new JsonResponse(processedModel,Response.Serializers.First(s => s.CanSerialize("application/json")));

response.Headers["Location"] = headerUri;

return response;
```

As I also want to return only json results, what would be the best solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you only want to return JSON you can do:

```
return Response.AsJson(model);
```

If you want to redirect the user you can do:

```
return Response.AsRedirect("url");
```

If you want to append headers to your JSON result you can use `.WithHeader(...)` like so:

```
return Response.AsJson(model).WithHeader("bananas", "are always yellow");
```

Here's a quick example where I return a image with headers:

```
return Response.FromStream(thumbStream, "image/png")
               .WithHeader("FileId", file.Id)
               .WithHeader("FileName", file.Name);
```